# Matlab: Reference to a handle object

Tags: matlab, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

Can I create a reference to a handle object in a way that I can replace the object itself at one point and the references will be updated?

Example:

```
classdef IShifter < handle
  methods (Abstract)
    x = Shift(this, x);
  end
end

classdef Shifter1 < IShifter
  methods
    function x = Shift(this, x)
      x = circshift(x, 1);
    end
  end
end

classdef Shifter2 < IShifter
  methods
    function x = Shift(this, x)
      x = [ 0 ; x ];
    end
  end
end



classdef Item
  properties (Access = 'private')
    shifter; % should be a pointer/reference to the object which is in the respective parent container object
  end

  methods
    function this = Item(shifter)
      this.shifter = shifter;
    end

    function x = test(this, x)
      x = this.shifter.Shift(x);
    end
  end
end

% note this is a value class, NOT a handle class!
classdef ItemContainer
  properties
     shifter;
     items;
  end

  methods
    function this = ItemContainer()
      this.shifter = Shifter1;
      this.items{1} = Item(this.shifter);
      this.items{2} = Item(this.shifter);
    end

    function Test(this)
      this.items{1}.Test( [ 1 2 3] )
      this.items{2}.Test( [ 1 2 3] )
    end
  end
end
```

Then, the output should be:

```
items = ItemContainer();
items.Test();
[ 3 1 2 ]
[ 3 1 2 ]
items.shifter = Shifter2;
items.Test();
[ 0 1 2 ]
[ 0 1 2 ]
```

But instead it is:

```
items = ItemContainer();
items.Test();
[ 3 1 2 ]
[ 3 1 2 ]
items.shifter = Shifter2;
items.Test();
[ 3 1 2 ]
[ 3 1 2 ]
```

because assigning a new Shifter object to parent object items does not update the references in the containers.

I am looking for something like in C where all the "shifter" properties are pointers and I can put whatever Shifter object I want into this "address".

ItemContainer and Item are not handle classes.
I want to avoid using events to update the references or implementing a set method to update the references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pass-by-reference concept in Matlab only goes so far (and is mostly limited to `handle`-classes anyway). It does not go as far as you'd like it to go.

If you don't want to use a set method, you can make `items` a dependent property with a get method that returns `{this.shifter,this.shifter}`

According to your comments, `items` is a bit more complicated than just a cell array. Thus, you may want to set up your object with a property `itemsStore` (or `itemsCache`, or whatever name you prefer for something that temporarily stores `items`), and a dependent property `items`. The get method to `items` checks whether `itemsStore` is empty; if yes, it reconstructs the item array and stores it in `itemsStore`, if not, it just returns the contents of `itemStore`. Additionally, you need to add a set method to `shifter` that empties `itemsStore`, so that `items` needs to be recreated. Note that MLint will give you a warning that a set method for a property shouldn't write into another property. This warning is meant to tell you that when you have saved an object and then load it again from disk, all the set methods will be executed. Depending on the order of execution, set methods that write into other properties may create unexpected results. In your case, it's no problem because an emptied `itemStore` is something that your code is designed to handle. If you want, you can right-click on the MLint warning, disabling it for that line.

Comment: That's sad. But OK, in the worst case I'd be OK to use `get.shifter(this, shifter)` and update all items. However: "A set method for a non-dependent property should not access another property". I do not want to make items dependent because this is just a toy example. In reality, my objects are much more complicated ... Suggestions?

Comment: Another unlean issue with with using `set.shifter`: `Item` is of type `IItem` (interface) but **not** all possible items have a property `shifter`. If the object has, it is assigned in the constructor. Hence, the `set.shifter` method would have need to check the type (or if the property exists) before blindly updating all item objects in the list. Not very elegant :(

Comment: @divB: I understand. In that case, a get method for items would be more elegant, as it would collect all the current elements as they are needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate this quickly? Do you mean to define `items` as dependent and dynamically create the objects in a loop within the `get` method? This would work. However, `items` would be accessed very frequently within loops and recreating the whole object hierarchy on every read access may be very inefficient. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @divB: yes, that's what I meant above. For frequent access, the following has served me well in the past: you can make `items` a dependent property that reads from `itemsCache`, a hidden property that caches the object hierarchy. The set method for e.g. `shifter` would set `itemsStore` to empty, so that the next call to `items` had to rebuild the cache, but subsequent calls to the get method would simply read from the cache, which would be a lot faster.

Comment: That sounds promising. I guess `itemsCache`==`itemsStore` above? Just one issue left: When I set `this.itemsCache = [];` within `set.shifter(this, shifter)` I again get the warning: "A set method for a non-Dependent property should not access another property ('itemsCache')". I guess this is OK in this case? Is there a way to make this more elegant/remove the warning?

Comment: @divB: the warning is not a problem - see my edit to the answer.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I am afraid there is a big problem still: itemsCache is not stored when I set it in the `get.items` function. The result is that `itemsCache` is always empty and hence the `get.items` always rebuilds the whole array from scratch. I'm afraid this could be because `ItemContainer` is a value (and not handle) object ... and must be. Can this be true? If so, any other way out?

Comment: @divB: Indeed, value classes make this more complicated. But only a bit: create a method `getItems` that returns both the items and the updated object, instead of using a dependent property.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible in Matlab.

However, you can use a set method or [`subsasgn`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html) to redefine the content of `items{1}` and `items{2}` when `item` is defined. Then you will be able to get the behavior you're asking for.

Best,

Comment: Maybe my toy example was a bit misleading. My objects are actually much more complicated and it's not just a list of static items. Maybe it's better to understand it this way: `ItemContainer` is a whole hierarchy of equations. The individual elements are `Item`. The way how (possible) time shifts occur (e.g. zero padding, circular shift) should be set using an IShifter instance. But the shifter should be set on the equation object, not on the individual elements which are internal. Any suggestions?